# Как правильно делать транзакции в многопоточном приложении?

Tags: mysql, node.js

пишу приложение на node.js

делаю транзакции к mysql, https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#transactions

соединение с базой открывается при старте приложения

и все транзакции пишутся через него

в связи с этим хочется правильно реализовать многопоточность и сохранить нормальную скорость

вопросы:

1. как лучше открывать транзакцию через `beginTransaction` или `START
   TRANSACTION`?
2. имеет ли смысл открывать/закрывать соединение для каждой транзакции (опасаюсь потери скорости на многократное соединение)

`UPDATE`

а как будут реализованы транзакции при таком раскладе?:

```
00:00:00 beginTransaction1;
00:00:01 sql1-1;
00:00:02 beginTransaction2;
00:00:03 sql2-1;
00:00:04 sql1-2;
00:00:05 commit1;
00:00:06 sql2-2;
00:00:07 commit2;
```

транзакции между собой независимы или они нарушат друг друга?

Comment: по второму пункту: никакого смысла переотрывать коннекты нет. Достаточно одного соединения на поток

Comment: 1 - лучше использовать то, что удобнее. Один запрос - START TRANSACTION, много запросов - beginTransaction. 2 - это давно решенная проблема. Используйте стандартный пул соединений (mysql.createPool). Он сам определит, когда нужно создать новое соединение, а когда можно использовать старое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ на первый вопрос можно найти в [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

> `BEGIN` and `BEGIN WORK` are supported as aliases of `START TRANSACTION` for initiating a transaction. `START TRANSACTION` is standard SQL syntax, is the recommended way to start an ad-hoc transaction, and permits modifiers that `BEGIN` does not.

`START TRANSACTION` соответствует стандарту и позволяет задавать дополнительные параметры.

Второй вопрос требует более глубокого обсуждения. Транзакции в MySQL (и других СУБД тоже) существуют в рамках *сессии* или *подключения*. Если два потока вызовут `START TRANSACTION` для одного и того же подключения, вы получите не две автономные транзакции, а [одну](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html):

> Transactions cannot be nested. This is a consequence of the implicit commit performed for any current transaction when you issue a `START TRANSACTION` statement or one of its synonyms.

Второй вызов `START TRANSACTION` вызовет неявную фиксацию первой транзакции. В СУБД, которые поддерживают вложенные транзакции, например, в [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17276_01/html/gsg_xml_txn/java/nestedtxn.html)/[MS SQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189336(v=sql.105).aspx), второй вызов `START TRANSACTION` начнёт вложенную транзакцию.

Таким образом, вы *обязаны* создавать новое подключение для каждой транзакции, если хотите сделать их независимыми. Чтобы делать это быстро, используют такую технику, как *пул подключений*. Я не специалист в `node.js`, но судя по Google, там есть поддержка [пулов](https://javascript.ru/forum/node-js-io-js/57252-nodejs-i-mysql-pool-connetctions.html).

[Подробнее о пулах подключений](https://habrahabr.ru/post/194142/).